# Can you select the desired number of Voronoi centers in QHull / Matlab

Tags: performance, matlab, nearest-neighbor, voronoi, qhull

I want to implement a Voronoi k-nearest neighbor solution from ["Nearest neighbors in high-dimensional data?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5769967/363829) I am currently using [MATLAB's `voronoin`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/voronoin.html) to calculate Voronoi vertices and bins. This function uses [Qhull](http://www.qhull.org/).

The problem is that with over 5 million states across 6 dimensions, the function just hangs. Is there a way to limit Qhull to `n` numbre of vertices? If not, is there an alternative path I can take?

Comment: Are you interesting only in Matlab solutions?

Comment: @G.Samaras I am interested in a solution that can at least interface with MATLAB. Feel free to post any solution though, I can always (maybe) adapt it to MATLAB.

Comment: One solution that comes to mind is not using Voronoi, but a tree-based approach that will find nearest neighbours. Are you interested?

Comment: Reading the algorithm, it seems that you don't really need to compute the polyhedra of the Voronoi Tessalation... To know in which polyhedron a point is, you just need to compute the 250 distances to the germs, and pick the nearest one.