# Find all k-nearest neighbors

Tags: algorithm, cluster-analysis, computational-geometry, hamming-distance

**Problem:**

I have N (~100m) strings each D (e.g. 100) characters long and with a low alphabet (eg 4 possible characters). I would like to find the k-nearest neighbors for every one of those N points ( k ~ 0.1D). Adjacent strings define via hamming distance. Solution doesn't have to be the best possible but closer the better.

**Thoughts about the problem**

I have a bad feeling this is a non trivial problem. I have read many papers and algorithms, however most of them has poor result in high dimension and it works when dimension is less than 5. For example [this paper](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02187718) suggests an efficient algorithm, but its constant is related to dimension exponentially.

Currently, I am investigating on how can I reduce dimension in a way that hamming distance is preserved or can be computed.

Another option is [locality sensitive hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_sensitive_hashing), Points that are close to each other under the chosen metric are mapped to the same bucket with high probability. Any Help? which option do you prefer?

Comment: "which is the k-nearest neighbor": do you mean "which are the k-nearest neighbors" ? And what is 100m ??

Comment: Yes, I have corrected. 100m indicates number of strings, so we have 100 million strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the previously asked questions has some good discussions, so you can refer to that,

[Nearest neighbors in high-dimensional data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751114/nearest-neighbors-in-high-dimensional-data)

Other than this, you can also look at,

http://web.cs.swarthmore.edu/~adanner/cs97/s08/papers/dahl_wootters.pdf

Few papers which analyze different approaches,

http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume11/radovanovic10a/radovanovic10a.pdf

https://www.cse.ust.hk/~yike/sigmod09-lsb.pdf

Comment: I remember having seen other very similar questions about string similarity with a small alphabet. Try searching some more here on SO.

Comment: All material you mentioned is related to continuous space, and I think changing discrete space to continuous don't work since data isn't spread in all space. In addition, measurement in my problem is hamming distance, however those materials use Euclidean distance.