# How can i avoid for loop for KNN search?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

My goal is to have the k nearest neighbours of each data point. I would like to avoid the use of a for loop with lookup and use something else simultaneously on each `rdd_distance` point, but I can't figure out how to do this.

```
parsedData = RDD[Object]
//Object have an id and a vector as attribute
//sqdist1 output is a Double

var rdd_distance = parsedData.cartesian(parsedData)
  .flatMap { case (x,y) =>
    if(x.get_id != y.get_id) 
      Some((x.get_id,(y.get_id,sqdist1(x.get_vector,y.get_vector))))
    else None
  }
for(ind1 <- 1 to size) {
  val ind2 = ind1.toString
  val tab1 = rdd_distance.lookup(ind2)
  val rdd_knn0 = sc.parallelize(tab1)
  val tab_knn = rdd_knn0.takeOrdered(k)(Ordering[(Double)].on(x=>x._2))
}
```

Is that possible without use a for loop with lookup ?

Comment: Look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751114/nearest-neighbors-in-high-dimensional-data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code solves your question (but inefficient when the number of `parsedData` is big).

```
  rdd_distance.groupByKey().map {
    case (x, iterable) =>
      x -> iterable.toSeq.sortBy(_._2).take(k)
  }
```

So this is more appropriate solution.

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.rdd.MLPairRDDFunctions._    

rdd_distance.topByKey(k)(Ordering.by(-_._2)) // because smaller is better.
```

Note that this code is included `Spark 1.4.0`. If you use the earlier version, use this code instead https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/rdd/MLPairRDDFunctions.scala

The idea of `topBykey` is to use `BoundedPriorityQueue` with `aggregateByKey` which retains top k items.

Comment: Unfortunately, parsedData is big, and i want to avoid groupByKey which is, on what i read, not enought performant.

Comment: Right, so you need to take a look at `topByKey`.

Comment: Is there an equivalent which gives me the minByKey rather than topByKey or this is the by(-_._2) which do the trick.